# Why the User Profile service is missing the Synchronization links inside sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, user-profile, user-profile-service

I am working on a SharePoint online tenant, and when i click on the User Profile service link, i found the following:-

[image]

where it is missing the Synchronization links, which were available inside the on-premises farm, as follow:-

[image]

so can i conclude that user profile synchronization will be handled automatically for us inside sharepoint online tenant? and we do not have to worry about syncing the user profile info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is handled automatically for you. You do not have to worry about synchronization.